# Открытие и навигация по сайту через C#

Tags: c#

Я использую для открытия сайта компонент `WebBrowser` в *C#*. При запуске формы, нужный сайт показывает сообщение, что у меня устаревшая версия веб браузера, хотя "Хром" у меня последней версии и студия 10-й версии. Как мне это исправить? Или как, например, открыть этот сайт через другой браузер?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) вместо компонента webBrowser. WebKit.NET - это контрол WinForms, являющийся оберткой над WebKit, написанной на C#.